# Placing each record on separate page using ArcMap Report Designer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, reports

I'm using the ArcMap Report Designer (ArcGIS 10.2.2) for the first time.  I need to generate a report where each database record appears on a separate page.

There is a "Page Break" Design Element.  But I can't find a way to put this at the end of the Detail area for a record.  I can get it close to the end; it creates a page break that puts a tiny portion of the record detail on the next page, followed by the next record.  This will work, but it's a bit ugly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past the following worked for me:

Click on the `detail` part of the Report, under the Data property (in the element properties section) change the property for `new page` depending on what you want you can use, `before, after or before and after` The `before` keeps your column heads and subsequent rows on the same page, I think the `after` does something weird like leaving your column heads on the previous page and taking all your data to the new page. The `before and after` is useful when you want an intermediate title page between different sections. Try each of them out, I'm sure you will find the one that works for your case. [image]

Comment: glad it helped :)