# Making a single report per each feature in a feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, feature-class, reports

I have been trying to figure out how to make an individual report for each record in a feature class.

The feature class is single point features and I do not want the report tool kicking out all of the information for each point feature that was collected in the field in a single report.

Rather, I would like each point to have its own report with its own attachments.

I have searched around on how to accomplish this but nothing has been helpful.

For example. When the report template runs it goes through each record, adds the information and its attachments then moves on to the next record. So what happens is that there is multiple records in one PDF file. I only want one record.

Comment: Can you expand more what you want in the report and what kind of attachments?

Comment: I have all of the information and attachments sorted and it is working. I'm sorry if I confused you.  Let me give a little background about what information we are collecting. We are inspecting power line poles. The technicians in the field are using collector to drop a dot where the pole is. They fill out the information in collector, attach photos and submit it to ArcGIS Online. From there we need to generate reports for each structure that has an issue. Arcmap is kicking out a continuous report for each feature in a layer. We would like to have a single report for each feature.

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: I edited the original question. Hope that helps. Sorry for the delay on the edit. Been down and out with the flu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is by placing a page break in your report designer layout as outlined in this post [Placing each record on separate page using ArcMap Report Designer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/173582/35779)

As mentioned in the post above:

> Click on the `detail` part of the Report, under the Data property (in the element properties section) change the property for `new page` depending on what you want you can use, `before, after or before and after` The `before` keeps your column heads and subsequent rows on the same page, I think the `after` does something weird like leaving your column heads on the previous page and taking all your data to the new page. The `before and after` is useful when you want an intermediate title page between different sections. Try each of them out, I'm sure you will find the one that works for your case.

Essentially by clicking on details then setting the new page option to whichever page break setting you prefer you can have a single record within the report on individual pages.

[image]